# Conditional filtering array with map JavaScript

Tags: javascript, filter

I'm trying to get a new array of tracks that have the same genre music id that genreFilter.

So if genreFilter is 12 I need the new array have tracks with genre music id = 12. But the list of genres is other array so I think I need iterate it too and then return the track.

I'm doing the next

```js
const list = tracks
      .map((track) =>
        track.primary_genres.music_genre_list.filter((genre) => {
          if (
            genre.music_genre &&
            genre.music_genre.music_genre_id === genreFilter
          ) {
            return track;
          }
        })
      );
```

But this only return genres which is obtained by filter function and doesn't return the track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your desired output is an array of tracks, you should `.filter` on the `tracks` array instead. Inside the filter, check if `.some` of the `music_genre_id`s are equal to the `genreFilter`:

```
const list = tracks.filter(
  track => track.primary_genres.music_genre_list.some(
    genre => genre.music_genre?.music_genre_id === genreFilter
  )
);
```

Use optional chaining to make things concise. If you can't use optional chaining, then it'd have to be similar to what you were doing originally:

```
genere => (
  genre.music_genre &&
  genre.music_genre.music_genre_id === genreFilter
)
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much. I didn't know that I can ask for a property in line with the sign ?